# Type of spurious reasoning which ignores other effects of a counterfactual

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, rhetoric, philosophy

Consider a male athlete who is a reasonably skilled 100 metres sprinter, with a best time around 10.3 seconds. Probably not enough to make a career in track and field, but faster than the [women's 100 metres record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_100_metres_world_record_progression) of 10.49 seconds, enough for him to declare:

> What a shame I was not born a woman, for then I would have been a record-breaking champion instead of an amateur.

This reasoning is clearly flawed because if he had been born a woman, he would not have run 10.3 seconds.

I think this mode of spurious reasoning, in which the side-effects of a counterfactual are ignored, is reasonably common in practice, but is there a name or expression which describes it? Either the technical name of this particular fallacy, or a phrase or idiom which alludes to it, would both be welcome.

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [Philosophy.SE] rather than EL&U. Though I do believe we have a `[rhetoric]` tag...

Comment: Take your pick: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about posting on Philosophy, but I'd be quite happy with a non-technical answer that expressed the same idea - I wouldn't be surprised if there were an idiom for it, for instance.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks, that's one of my favourite Wikipedia lists (another is the [list of cognitive biases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases)) but I can't see what I'm looking for on there. Although I might have missed it, or more likely, not noticed how it is a special instance of one of those listed.

Comment: From the Wiki article, Fallacy of the Single Cause (Causal Oversimplification) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_single_cause  In your example, the runner focuses on his performance while ignoring the contributing factor of his maleness.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I think you're right to identify that the issue is the athlete ignoring the impact of his maleness. But I'm not sure "fallacy of the single cause" is right, because the athlete does not seem to be positing any cause at all. It doesn't seem to fit in to "X occurred after Y. Therefore, Y caused X" (where the flaw is that actually "A,B,C...etc. also caused X").

Comment: I feel like your assumption that he wouldn't have run 10.3 as a woman is sexist.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be specific fallacy of inconsistency that is labeled *[false equivalence:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence)*

> a logical fallacy which describes a situation where there is a logical
> and apparent equivalence, but when in fact there is none. This fallacy
> is categorized as a fallacy of inconsistency.

The *false equivalence* is in the assumption that being born a woman is the same as being born a man, when in fact there are many genetic, physiological and sociological differences that would have an impact on the outcome.

The syllogism:

> 100 m in 10.3 s is an amateur time for men
>
> I ran 100 m in 10.3 s
>
> ∴I am an amateur.

Has no logical equivalence to:

> 100 m in 10.3s is a world record time for women
>
> I ran 100 m in 10.3 s
>
> ∴I am a world record holder.

The *false equivalence*, generates a *false minor premise*, because it was a **man** who ran 100 m in 10.3 s.

You cannot change your past, but **if** you could, it would change your present.

Comment: (+1) I am still thinking about this answer. The situation I described does not seem to fit in to quite the same mold as "They're both soft, cuddly pets. There's no difference between a cat and a dog" or "We're all born naked. We're all no different from each other", which are clear examples of false equivalence. I wonder whether there is a more specific name for the "ignoring other effects of a counterfactual" as it is a fallacy I see regularly.